# Pack a p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

In Swing, you can call `pack(`) which will make the frame that is displaying contents shrink to the size of its contents.

Here is the JavaDoc for it: [pack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29)

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. If the window and/or its owner are not yet displayable, both are made displayable before calculating the preferred size. The Window will be validated after the preferredSize is calculated.

Is there a corresponding way to do this in a PrimeFaces dialog. Namely, can I make a dialog shrink to fit its contents?

Comment: It does that already by default. Did you set a fixed width or so?